# How do I get a literal expression from a custom directive in Vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to transfer a Vue 1.x custom directive to Vue 2.x and I can't find anywhere how to get my expressions again as a literal. Let's say this example is my custom directive:

```
<div v-custom="file.txt"></div>
```

In Vue1

```js
Vue.directive('custom', function () {
  console.log(this.expression)
})
```

will return "file.txt" as a string.

In Vue2

```js
Vue.directive('custom', {
  bind: function (el, binding) {
    console.log(binding.expression)
  }
})
```

will return

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "file" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option

and

> [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'txt' of undefined"

This means my expression in Vue2 is no longer a string, but a variable. How do I get it to return a string now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply wrap your text in single quotes to make it a string literal.  However, as noted in your comment, if trying to access `binding.expression`, it will include the wrapping single quotes.  Instead, you should use the `binding.value` property.

**Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-custom="'file.txt'"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
Vue.directive('custom', {
  bind: function (el, binding) {
    console.log(binding.value)
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j17aoLL7/3/).

Comment: This does make the expression literal, but also adds the single quotes to the string. I was hoping there was a solution where I don't have to strip out the quotes to get the result I want.

Comment: That is correct, since you are literally requesting the binding expression.  I've updated my answer.  You can grab the value directly off of `binding.value` which contains the unwrapped string literal.

Comment: Yes, the answer now returns the string as in Vue1. Completely different method.